# Send WM_NCHITTEST from win32k system (Windows itself)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, window, caption

So I have a window with one child window that takes up the full window.

```
SendMessageW(MainWindow, WM_NCHITTEST, 0, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
```

The code above is sent to the main window when the mouse enteres the child window. It works, however, the result returned from MainWindow's WindowProc is just returned by `SendMessageW`, and then discarded.

**Thus, actions like dragging or resizing the main window will not work because Windows itself is not sending the `WM_NCHITTEST` message. The child window is.**

So how can I force windows to send a `WM_NCHITTEST` message to a window whenever I want, so that actions like dragging the window are then possible?

Thanks.

Comment: The point is that you don't send `WM_NCHITTEST`, Windows does. You need to make your child window return the right value to make Windows think it's a dragging or resizing area.

Comment: The child window should not overlap the non-client area of the main window. Do you have some scenario where this overlap is necessary?

Comment: Yes. My window is a borderless window - see https://github.com/rossy/borderless-window/blob/master/borderless-window.c My child window is a C++/WinRT Xaml Islands window.

Comment: Are you mean that you want to drag or resize the main window by clicking on the child window?

Comment: No, I just want to the OS send a WM_NCHITTEST message to the parent window so that I can drag and resize it. Because right now, the WM_NCHITTEST message is being captured by the child window only.

Answer (score 0):

The way I can think of is to install the message hook through [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) and then forward the message to MainWindow with `SendMessage`.

Comment: Does not work. Windows.UI.CoreWindow does not capture WM_NCHITTEST messages when used with SetWindowsHookEx. Tried to hook CallWndProc and GetMessage. I also tried adding WS_EX_TRANSPARENT flag to the window, still does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found how to make it work.

You need to set `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` and then disable the window. I disabled it with `EnableWindow(MainWindow, FALSE);`

But it works now and the hittest messages are going to the main window that is underneath it.